# Anko logging methods cannot be resolved

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions, anko

I'm trying to get my hands on Anko and came across this problem.
On its documentation it says that Anko has a  [convenience methods for logging](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/blob/master/doc/ADVANCED.md#logging), I tried it but Android Studio doesn't automatically import it, so I manually import it as you can see in the screenshot. However it's still being marked as unresolved.

[image: debug-statement-not-resolved]

Here's my gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
compile 'org.jetbrains.anko:anko-sdk15:0.8.2'
compile 'org.jetbrains.anko:anko-support-v4:0.8'
compile 'org.jetbrains.anko:anko-appcompat-v7:0.8'
```

}

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the link that you posted the class adds the `AnkoLogger` trait. Also, the gray import doesn't mean that it's unresolved. It means that it's unused. The red `debug` is unresolved. Both of these are because you haven't added the  `AnkoLogger` trait.

```
class SomeActivity : Activity(), AnkoLogger {
```